# Unable to retrieve meta data from smart contract

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, solidity, vite, thirdweb

I have created a crowdfunding platform on react and used thirdweb to build my smart contract, but when I run the app it throws an error in the console saying unable to retrive metadata from {address}.

ERROR: -

Error: Could not resolve metadata for contract at 0x2F36018c1dE586bf996203A0eB087B28592e4A5a
at fetchContractMetadataFromAddress (contract-publisher-a603197e.browser.esm.js:4339:13)

I tried using different testnets but it didnt workout

Answer (score 0):

I see your contract on goerli here: https://thirdweb.com/goerli/0x2F36018c1dE586bf996203A0eB087B28592e4A5a/sources

make sure you're initializing the SDK with the right `activeChain` in your `ThirdwebProvider`.

```
<ThirdwebProvider activeChain="goerli" clientId="your_client_id">...</ThirdwebProvider>
```